# Create a CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fputcsv

I need to create a CSV file from a PHP array, I'm aware of the `fputcsv()` function. I've a recollection that a better function exists for this kind of stuff but I can't find it nor remember it's name.

Does anyone know of such function or am I imagining?

---

I might be making some confusion with the `fgetcsv()` function and the `str_getcsv()` equivalent.

Comment: What does `fputcsv()` not do for you?

Comment: @Kitson: `fputcsv()` does everything for me, it's lovely. =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fputcsv`](http://php.net/fputcsv) is to write an array into a file with CSV format. [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) is to read data from a file with CSV format and convert it into an array. And [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) is to convert a string in CSV format into an array.

So `fputcsv` and `fgetcsv` are their respective inverses. And `fgetcsv` could be a function that uses `str_getcsv`.

Comment: I know that, but `fgetcsv()` is to `str_getcsv()` as `fputcsv()` is to `...`?

Comment: @Alix Axel: Ah, now I get what you’re asking form. Well, PHP has no such function. But there are some suggestions in the comments to http://php.net/str_getcsv that use a temporary stream buffer that can be written with `fputcsv` and then be read.

Comment: Something that converts a an array into a CSV string but PHP isn't really well known for it's stdlib API design and I can't seem to find an actual function that does this.

Comment: Sorry, sometimes I've some trouble expressing myself well in English. Thanks for the confirmation though, my brain tricked me on this one. =)